# Can't connect Websphere MQ Queue Manager

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm a beginner on WebSphere MQ, I was working on MQ 6 and it was working fine, but now I've installed MQ 7.1 and when I try to create a new Queue Manager I can do it But it can't connect and it gives me the following error :

[image]

Do you have any idea about that? Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look up any WebSphere MQ error code if either the WebSphere MQ Client or Server are installed using the `mqrc` command.  In this case:

```
C:\Users\MUSR_MQADMIN>mqrc 2059

      2059  0x0000080b  MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

The 2059 usually indicates that the listener is not running or the queue manager is down.  There's a different error code if the listener is running and the QMgr name is wrong and another one if the connection is made to the right QMgr but the channel name is wrong.  Sometimes you can get a 2059 if the channel was closed at the server side by an exit but since you didn't mention any exits, I'm assuming in this case that its  listener problem.

Hopefully by now you are defining a listener object rather than using `inetd` or the `runmqlsr` command.  Defining an object and setting it to start and stop under QMgr control is the most reliable way to configure it.

Once you get past the 2059, you should be aware that as of WMQ V7.1, the queue managers are secure by default and won't accept *any* remote client connections unless you explicitly authorize them.  This is the opposite of the behavior of V6 where on a newly defined queue manager running a listener, anyone with a TCP route to it could administer it and remotely execute OS code as the `mqm` user.  So I expect that the next problem you run into will be 2035 errors.

I've been told this means more work for the WMQ administrator.  The only case in which that's true is if the V6 or earlier queue manager had been configured without security.  If the tasks to secure a V7.0 QMgr are compared to the tasks to provision access on a v7.1 and higher QMgr are compared, provisioning access turnds out to be easier.  However if you liked the V7.0 behavior, you can always alter the QMgr to disable `CHLAUTH` rules.  Needless to say, leaving security enabled is highly encouraged.

To debug security errors, alter the QMgr to enable authorization events using the `runmqsc` command `ALTER QMGR AUTHOREV(ENABLED)`.  Next, download and install [*SupportPac MS0P*](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMS0P) into WebSphere MQ Explorer.  Then when you do get a security error, use WebSphere MQ Explorer to look at the queue.  Right-click on the queue and select the option to parse the event messages.  This will tell you in excruciating detail all the information you need to debug the authorization error.

Finally, if you wish to read up on the new security features, go to [t-rob.net/links](http://t-rob.net/links) and look at the conference presentations there.  There are also some articles indexed if you scroll down.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't install MQ client or MQ Server, I've only installed the WebSphere MQ Distribution platform here : http://ibm.co/X7SXF6 . Should I install the client and the server to use the `mqrc` command ?

Comment: The WMQ Explorer (SupportPac MS0T that you linked to) has its own built-in client and isn't meant to be the redistributable client.  It doesn't have all the features that the full WMQ Java client does.  For what it's worth, I've asked the lab to include mqrc in the Explorer install.  In any case, glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

In the screen-shot, I see hostname "127.0.0.1" and port # 1414.  If it is a local queue manager then connect directly to it.

Also, each queue manager MUST use a unique port number. If you had it working with WMQ v6 queue manager, is this the same queue manager?  If not, then make sure each queue manager uses a different port number (i.e. 1415, 1416, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem. but i resolved this by :
1. created a listener manually (define lstr(lstr1) port(xxxx) control(qmgr)
2. setmqaut mcauser('mqm').