# MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE while using managed client

Tags: c#-4.0, ssl-certificate, ibm-mq, mq

Received signed certificate, installed in windows user cert. store with the public key from MQ, but getting MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE error?

```
 <add key="sslCertStore" value="*USER"/> 
 <add key="SslCipherSpec" value="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"/>
```

What's missing?

**EDIT**
One more question - where certificates should be placed to be available using

```
<add key="sslCertStore" value="*SYSTEM"/>
```

Comment: Did you saw this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15078901/213550 ?

Comment: Thank you, yes - looked at it. not my case

Comment: Are you using MQ V8?   
    Import the obtained client side SSL Certificate to the the Windows Certificate Store. (Under COMPUTER/USER account).
 This blog may be useful to you:  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/mq_v8_dot_net_samples_can_create_ssl_connection_in_managed_mode?lang=en

Comment: Have you been able to validate that the QM is started and running correctly? As you are not getting a security exception?

Comment: This exception has nothing to do with SSL. Check the address you are trying to reach the QM on, and that the QM is running and listening for connections.

Comment: it works when security is optional, so it is SSL

Comment: @Atilla - when SSL is optional on the server it all magically works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the comments and question i see you mention

> Received signed certificate, installed in windows user cert store with the public key from MQ

and

> when SSL is optional on the server it all magically works

From this i believe you are trying to connect a client into your Queue Manager where the client application has it's own certificate. Because you have not specified a certificate for the client to use i don't believe the client is connecting with the (signed) certificate you added to the windows certificate store. This is why it works when the SSL is set to optional but does not work when the SSL is set to required. (Assuming you are talking about the SSLCAUTH attribute on the channel)

From [this knowledge center page](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q120650_.htm) i believe you need to add the following:

```
<add key="CertificateLabel" value="certificatelabel"/>
```

replacing *certificatelabel* with the label of the certificate you want the client to use.